# How to upsert based on values from another table?

Tags: postgresql, peewee

I'm trying to UPSERT into postgres DB based on values from another table using PeeWee.

```
**table1**
pk_t1 int
name
city
country
```

```
**table2**
pk_t2 int
name
city
country
comments
```

```sql
INSERT INTO table2 (pk_t2, name, city, country) 
SELECT pk_1, name, city, country
FROM   table1
ON     CONFLICT (pk_t2) DO UPDATE  
SET    name = excluded.name, city = excluded.city, country = excluded.country;
```

But I'm unable to find a suitable peewee example from documents or SO.

Comment: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#executing-queries

Comment: You can specify a FROM clause on an UPDATE query: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Update.from_ -- see the docs for examples and experiment until you get what you want.

Comment: @coleifer I tried using the update query. It only updates existing records. I'm trying to INSERT (if record does not exist) and Update (if record exists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
q = T1.select()

iq = (T2
      .insert_from(q, fields=[T2.id, T2.name, T2.city, T2.country])
      .on_conflict(conflict_target=[T2.id], preserve=[T2.name, T2.city, T2.country]))
```

Corresponding SQL peewee generates:

```
insert into t2 (id, name, city, country)
select t1.id, t1.name, t1.city, t1.country
from t1
on conflict(id) do update set 
  name=excluded.name,
  city=excluded.city,
  country=excluded.country
```

Comment: Works perfectly.